# Understand output of range-diff

Tags: git, git-range-diff

I rebased my feature branch over master and want to verify that I resolved all merge conflicts correctly.

I'm using git range-diff for that purpose:

```
git range-diff --dual-color  old-master..origin/my-branch new-master..my-branch
```

I've read the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff) trice, but still I'm having trouble understanding the output of range-diff. I'd appreciate if someone could help me with that.

I'm having trouble understanding diffs like this

```
 6:  1273567d876 !  6:  789a6775664 A-commit-message
    @@ Commit message
     
      ## some/path/something.php ##
     @@ some/path/something.php: function initTexts() {
    -             "text-a",
    -             "text-b",
    -             "text-c",
    +             "text-x",
    +             "text-y",
    +             "text-z",
     +            "text-added-in-the-commit-a",
     +            "text-added-in-the-commit-b",
              ] as $key) {
```

Note that

1. the first three lines are dimmed and the `-`  has a red background,
2. the next three lines are bold and the `-`  has a green background,
3. and the last two lines are green, with no background

The way I read the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff#Documentation/git-range-diff.txt---no-dual-color)

1. should indicate a line that was removed in the first commit range
2. should indicate a line that was added in the second commit range
3. should indicate a line that was added in both commit ranges

### What I do not understand

1. Why are there even `-`  indicators, since no lines were actually deleted. Only new lines were added. The lines with `-`  are also present in the second range.
2. Why are `"text-a",`, `"text-b",`, `"text-c",`, `"text-x",`, `"text-y",` and `"text-z",` in the diff, but not for example `"text-unrelated-22",`.
3. The selection of lines in the diff seems arbitrary to me.
4. What should `@@ Commit message` tell me?

### More information

First, `git show` shows me, that both commits indeed intended to do the same change.

```
git show 1273567d876
             "text-c",
+            "text-added-in-the-commit-a",
+            "text-added-in-the-commit-b",
         ] as $key) {

git show 789a6775664
             "text-z",
+            "text-added-in-the-commit-a",
+            "text-added-in-the-commit-b",
         ] as $key) {
```

If I check out the commits under question, we see that both had to apply the changes to different starting situation, which is expected:

```
git checkout 1273567d876 && (show content of some/path/something.php: function initTexts())10

            […]
            "text-unrelated-6",
            "text-a",
            "text-b",
            "text-c",
            "text-added-in-the-commit-a",
            "text-added-in-the-commit-b",
        ] as $key) {
```

```
git checkout 789a6775664 && (show content of some/path/something.php: function initTexts())

            […]
            "text-unrelated-6",
            "text-a",
            "text-b",
            "text-c",
            "text-unrelated-7",
            […]
            "text-unrelated-22",
            "text-x",
            "text-y",
            "text-z",
            "text-added-in-the-commit-a",
            "text-added-in-the-commit-b",
        ] as $key) {
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be whitespace difference? Tab vs spaces.

Comment: @KamilCuk I just checked and couldn't find a whitespace difference.

Comment: It's possible that `git range-diff` picked the wrong diffs to diff. (Though, looking again, I'm not sure that this explains what you're seeing. It does happen with range-diff sometimes, though.) I think in this case, what happened is that the range-diff code fed, to the diff engine, text that made the diff engine itself misfire and pick the wrong original sections.

Comment: That is, as you noted: "we see that both had to apply the changes to different starting situation" - if you run the two `git diff`s one at a time, each picks a different start from which to generate a diff, but range-diff has fancy optimizations and may pick the *same* start both times by mistake. This makes it show the wrong diff-of-diffs. (Also, I have a vague memory of a recent bug report on the Git mailing list, of `git range-diff` having just this sort of problem, introduced in some particular recent-ish Git version during improvement of diffs in other tricky corner cases.)